# how to select multiple rows using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I had two tables

1. ads

[image]

2. adImages

[image]

here table **ads** *id* and table **adImages** *adsId* are same. here i have to select all the rows from the table **ads** and **adImages**, and display it in json format.

My codes looks:

```
$query="SELECT a.*, b.images FROM `ads` AS a INNER JOIN `adImages` AS b ON a.id = b.adsId";

$result=mysql_query($query);
$value = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($value>=1)
{   
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $details[] = array(

        'id' => $row['id'], 
        'location' => $row['location'],
        'title'=>$row['title'],
        'mobile' => $row['mobile'],
        'description' => $row['description'],
        'category' => $row['category'],
        'images' =>'http://greenwma.com/dev/uploads/'.$row['images'],
        );
    }
    echo  json_encode($details);
}
```

And its output json looks like :

```
[{"id":"10","location":"9.982852,76.300637","title":"Ggg","mobile":"5555555","description":"Google","category":"BusMedia","images":"http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016062319:07:39.jpg{"id":"10","location":"9.982852,76.300637","title":"Ggg","mobile":"5555555","description":"Google","category"BusMedia","images":"http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 17:27:05.jpg"},{"id":"11","location":"9.962439,76.305337","title":"Test","mobile":"898566899","description":"Test","category":"Bus Shelters","images":"http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 19:15:16.jpg"},{"id":"11","location":"9.962439,76.305337","title":"Test","mobile":"898566899","description":"Test","category":"Bus Shelters","images":"http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 19:08:50.jpg"},{"id":"11","location":"9.962439,76.305337","title":"Test","mobile":"898566899","description":"Test","category":"Bus Shelters","images":"http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 19:07:39.jpg"}]
```

here the problem is ***id,location,title,mobile,description,category*** are repeating for each image on same **adsId**.

And my need is that, I have to get json in the format

```
[{"id":"10","location":"9.982852,76.300637","title":"Ggg","mobile":"5555555","description":"Google ","category":"Bus Media","images":"http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 19:07:39.jpg","http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 17:27:05.jpg"},{"id":"11","location":"9.962439,76.305337","title":"Test","mobile":"898566899","description":"Test","category":"Bus Shelters","images":"http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 19:15:16.jpg","http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 19:08:50.jpg","http:\/\/greenwma.com\/dev\/uploads\/MapCapture2016-06-23 19:07:39.jpg"}]
```

that is, I have to get all images separated by comma in single json object. for that what all changes should I make in the above code.

Comment: Why are you still using mysql_* functions? You know they are deprecated right?

Comment: Agreed. Whatever reason you are using `mysql_xxx()` functions, you need to stop and learn to use the PDO library instead. The `mysl_xx()` functions have been removed from the most recent PHP versions, and had been considered bad practice for well over a decade before that. Your code is *seriously* behind the times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT() & [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with sub queries to do it in one query and lesser loops.

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(images) images FROM (
SELECT a.*, CONCAT('http://greenwma.com/dev/uploads/', b.images) images
FROM `ads` AS a 
INNER JOIN `adImages` AS b ON a.id = b.adsId 
) tbl
GROUP BY id
```